# How can the Open/Save/Cancel dialog be disabled in a C# .NET application Webbrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

When downloadable content/server side scripts give the .NET Webbrowser a downloadable file, a dialog box is opened prompting the user to open/save/cancel the download. How can this window be prevented from appearing/ be disabled?

Thanks in advance.

Note: This is for a custom download manager in a browser I am building.

Comment: What type of file?  Certain MIME types can be handled by the browser, such as PDF files and images.

Comment: To start with I am looking to trap binary files; so application/.... for example.

@ChadLaGuardia Please note I am not trying to make anything evil (this time), quite the reverse, a download manager for my custom browser. I simply do not want the IE dialog making a mess each time.

Comment: I have seen download managers in Flash that bypass the browser's UI, but for bare HTML/JavaScript I believe the dialog is deliberately inaccessible to the web page. I think the reason is obvious: removing the user's control over what gets downloaded when and to where is (as Chad says) "evil computer science". Even if *you* plan on using it for good.

Comment: I have already tried using the FileDownload and OnDownloadBegin event handlers, the latter in the more advanced IE wrapper I am using. The former fires off all the time - at each navigation and the latter has takes no parameters for me to play with - e.g. e.cancel = true;

PLEASE note: this is for a CUSTOM browser - I am not trying to disable anything in IE, just the dialog in the embedded form of it, the 'Webbrowser' component within my own application. I am adding a download manager not dissimilar to Firefox's window.

Comment: @James: I doubt this is possible. Again, *your* purposes are good, but it could easily be used for those not-so-good. This seems like the sort of thing where you're going to have to build the component yourself rather than using the `Webbrowser` component.

Answer (score 2):

To take over downloading you need to [implement IDownloadManager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327865).

To register your download manager for a webbrowser control instance, you need to implement IServiceProvider on [your IOleClientSite implementation](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windows.inetexplorer.ie5.programming.components.webbrowser_ctl/browse_thread/thread/8a7f5038432f328e) and return your download manager when SID_SDownloadManager service is requested.

An example can be found at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx. It is unclear which UI class library you are using, but you can use it in Windows Forms directly or in WPF via Windows Forms Interop.